# Set CLASSPATH on Mac

Tags: java, macos

Can someone please help me, I'm almost desperate because I can't find solutions for a Mac.

I have written two .java files that I would like to use as a library for all new projects.
For this I found out that I have to set the CLASSPATH.

The java files path:

```
/Users/thomas/Soft/IN_OUT/In.java
/Users/thomas/Soft/IN_OUT/Out.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with it. The concept of CLASSPATH is misguided in the first place (because you can run more than one java app, ever, on your system, setting the classpath globally is misguided as a concept), and on most platforms, libraries and tools, this isn't the intended way to configure classpaths.

For example, in IDEs, you configure classpaths on a per project basis.

When compiling code or with `javac` or running code with `java`, you can supply the classpath with the `-classpath` option (or shorten it to `-cp`). For running jar files (`java -jar foo.jar`, or double clicking a jar), the classpath is taken **solely** from the `Class-Path` manifest entry in that jar file; both the `-cp` and the global CLASSPATH variable are ignored.

I get that you want these files to be available to 'all projects', but that's just not how it works. If you update these files, all your old projects would break, or at least you'd have to consider if they might. You'd also be extending these files to eclipse, intellij, and any other java apps on your system which makes no sense. That's why this notion of 'make these available to everything' isn't a particularly sensible thing to want.

Comment: But I would need this for the UNI, the two files will not change. Is there no way to do this?

My colleagues who use Windows have done this with a few entries.

Comment: You can edit your bash profile and add it; whether some environment will get the update depends. As I said, bad idea. Don't do this.

Comment: Do you have a better option?
I use VS Code or Eclipse and I don't execute the command Javav manually. I will not always copy these two files into my projects.

Comment: Eclipse and VS Code are going to ignore CLASSPATH anyway. You need to add those source files to each project you want to use them in, or turn them into a jar and add that to every project instead.